# Prove that $ f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{\min\limits_{k\in Z} |4^n \cdot x - k|}{4^n} $ is cotinuous and is not differentiable.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, continuity

I have this exercise from elementary analysis:

Define the function $f: \mathbb R \to\mathbb R$ by

$$ f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{\min\limits_{k\in Z} |4^n \cdot x - k|}{4^n} $$

Prove that

(1) $f$ is continuous

and

(2) $f$ is not differentiable at any $x \in\mathbb R$

I noticed that this may have some similarity with the [Blancmange curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve) , and I think I could use the M-Test to prove the continuity but I have no clue how to prove that is not differentiable at any $x$.

Comment: It's very similar to the curve you mention and the argument for showing that its not differentiable is basically the same. You just need to make some minor adjustments that comes about from replacing $2^n$ with $4^n$ (you can adopt the proof on page 8 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.1691.pdf).